# Errors with data from array in d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm relatively new to D3 and I'm having some trouble loading from a csv. I found an example using a txt file so I've set that up but im still having issues using the data in D3 to change the height of a rect. 
When I use it I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
     });
});
    var lines = [];
function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split(', ');


    for (var i=0; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(', ');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {

            var tarr = [];
            for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
                tarr.push(data[j]);
                locs[data[j]] = data[j];
            }
            lines.push(tarr);
        };
    };
};

for(i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
console.log(lines)
    d3.selectAll("rect[id='" + String(lines[i][1]) + "']")
        .data(locations)
        .attr("transform-origin", "bottom")
        .attr("y", function(a) {
            var current_y = d3.select(this).attr("y")
            return current_y - lines[i][1];
        })
        .attr("height", lines[i][1]);
};
```

I know this is going to have a stupidly easy answer, and some stupid mistake in my messy code but I've been struggling with this for a few days and I've searched but nothing as worked for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: `return current_y - lines[i][1];` but `i` isn't the same as `I`

Comment: Thanks, but my original post didn't have those capitalised. Someone edited my post and capitalised those. I've made them back to 'i' again.

Comment: Have you confirmed the correct data is being passed in to `processData`? When are you trying to call the d3 functionality? Before the Ajax has returned? In other words, `processData` is correctly async-ified: what about the rest?